# Compile Jade to JSON?

Tags: node.js, pug

Odd idea, but looking for the simplest approach to define some data files in Jade, and then directly convert them to JSON.

I looked at extending Jade to support a custom doctype, but quickly got lost in the code.  For example:

```
doctype json
```

Only manual hacky approach I could come up with is convert the Jade to an XML file with jade, and then using better-require to read the XML file in node as an object, and then JSON.stringify the object (yikes)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use data/JSON in jade, instead of defining some data inside jade, you can pass json directly into response via `response.locals` or when returning `response.render(view, [locals], callback)` from [node](http://expressjs.com/api.html#res.locals).

In your app.js

```
res.local.data=JSON.stringify(dataobj);
//or pass variable when rendering
res.render('/index', {
    data : JSON.stringify(dataobj)
});
```

In your jade

```
function yourfunc(){
  var data = !{dataobj};
}
```

This is dynamic, you can control the variables you are sending into the file, unlike statically defining them in jade.